# Order of Values from a Django Foreign Key Reverse Lookup

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I have two models, Document and DocumentImage. Document has a primary key called document_id, and a foreign key to DocumentImage.

Say I have a list of document_ids and I run this query:

```
images = DocumentImage.objects.filter(document__in=document_ids)
```

as a reverse lookup through the foreign key relationship

Is it true that images[0] is derived from document_ids[0], and images[1] is derived from document_ids[1], etc?

I need to combine each element in images with each element in document_ids, and I want to make sure that I have the correct document_id for that element from images.

In other words, I want to do this:

```
for document_id, image in zip(document_ids, images):
    # associate the document_id with the image
```

and make sure that each image is associated with the correct document_id.

Thanks!

Mark

PS I may have answered my own question with this little test:

```
document_ids = [2970, 2944, 2943, 2940]
image_objects = DocumentImage.objects.filter(document__in=document_ids)
for image, id in zip(image_objects, document_ids):
    d2 = image.document_set.all()[0].document_id
    print("id=%s, d2=%s" % (id, d2))

id=2970, d2=2940
id=2944, d2=2943
id=2943, d2=2944
id=2940, d2=2970
```

I had hoped id and d2 would be the same. However, they seem to be in reverse order. I do not understand why. Nor, do I know if the result is quaranteed so I can use it to eliminate the image.document_set.all()[0].document_id to look up the document id.

I hope someone can help me understand what is going on here!

PPS
It seems the query DocumentImage.objects.filter(document__in=document_ids) sorts the document_ids list.

```
document_ids = [2940, 2943, 2944, 2970]
image_objects = DocumentImage.objects.filter(document__in=document_ids)
for image, id in zip(image_objects, document_ids):
    d2 = image.document_set.all()[0].document_id
    print("id=%s, d2=%s" % (id, d2))

id=2940, d2=2940
id=2943, d2=2943
id=2944, d2=2944
id=2970, d2=2970
document_ids = [2943, 2944, 2940, 2970]
image_objects = DocumentImage.objects.filter(document__in=document_ids)
for image, id in zip(image_objects, document_ids):
    d2 = image.document_set.all()[0].document_id
    print("id=%s, d2=%s" % (id, d2))

id=2943, d2=2940
id=2944, d2=2943
id=2940, d2=2944
id=2970, d2=2970
```

You will notice that the d2 values, which are the document_ids for each image, is always in sorted order, regardless of what order document_ids is passed to the DocumentImage query.

Anyone know why or if this is the normal operation of a query using __in=[a list of values]?

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: How is `document_ids` defined? You could use a `Document` query with `prefetch_related` to select all objects in two queries. The images for each `Document` can be accessed via `document.documentimage_set.all()`

Comment: document_ids is a list - [2345, 6754, 1290,] It comes from another query based on other parameters. There is a model, DocumentMetaData, that has a JSON field and a foreign key to Document. It lools like this (inside a loop with different values for decade - document_ids = list(DocumentMetaData.objects.filter(metadata__has_key='Decade').filter(metadata__Decade=decade).values_list('document_id', flat=True))